# multi install spaces

Tags: ros, release, deb, pre-release

I want to have both a release and pre-release version of my ros pack installed on a robot, so I can easily change between them.
my idea was to install the pre-release to a separate workspace in /opt/ros/pre-release and just source that workspace then I need the pre-release versions else the release version is installed under normal Ros.
but I cannot seem to find a way to create a Debian package to be installed in a different location

I am running Ros noetic on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I think with debian packages this will be difficult, but maybe you could also do this with different workspaces? Or have the release as debian and the pre-release as workspace? Than you could source the workspace or not depending on if you want to use the release or pre-release packages.

Comment: the idea was to have the release and pre-release easy to change to and then a dev workspace for development, I dint want to make to many workspace if It would be possible to use a installed version also for easy update

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a nice setup for a containerized solution like docker. You will need to do a little bit of work to launch the containers so they have the necessary permissions for the hardware and network.

You can download a docker container from Docker Hub (https://hub.docker.com/u/osrf) if you want different ROS libraries as well as your own processes.

Comment: i cant use docker containers as we have limited space as it is and I think docker container's fill use to much storage space

Comment: You say you need 2 copies of the ROS debs, which is going to be a problem if you don't have storage space. You could also consider a chroot environment.

Comment: do have some extra storage space but I don't want multiple complete ROS environments but only multiple of the packages I develop myself

Comment: Are all the packages you are looking to duplicate built from source? If so, @Lars' answer below is the way to go. Just remember to source the correct workspace when you open a new terminal.

If not, you're looking at some sort of containerizing.

Comment: If you want to use the same source but build with different options, you could probably set up multiple workspaces where the `src/` directory is linked to one true source directory. Then you'd need to make sure no one ever does a `--symlink-install` during build.

But this idea makes more sense if you have a CI system building your different versions and you just download and run the container with the built workspace.